# Error: 'Map' is not exported from 'react-leaflet' (imported as 'LeafletMap')

Tags: html, reactjs, leaflet

Here is my code:

```
import { Map as LeafletMap, TileLayer } from 'react-leaflet';

function Map() {
return (
    <div className="map">
        <LeafletMap>
            <TileLayer 
            url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
            attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright"> OpenStreetMap </a> contributors'/>
        </LeafletMap>
    </div>
```

But I got an error saying `Attempted import error: 'Map' is not exported from 'react-leaflet' (imported as 'LeafletMap').` I've tried changing the 'import { Map' to 'import { MapContainer' but still won't work. Instead I got another error saying:

```
./node_modules/@react-leaflet/core/esm/path.js 10:41
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (10:41)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|   useEffect(function updatePathOptions() {
|     if (props.pathOptions !== optionsRef.current) {
>       const options = props.pathOptions ?? {};
|       element.instance.setStyle(options);
|       optionsRef.current = options;
```

I also tried changing the react-leaflet version from ^3.2.1 to ^2.7.0 and leaflet from ^1.7.1 to ^1.6.0. But still no luck. Any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to explicitly transpile `react-leaflet` because the maintainer is not understanding they should change their transpilation target to a lower version in order to more fully support the nullish coalescing operator: https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/issues/877#issuecomment-841871904

You can try adding this to your babel config

```js
{
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator"]
}
```

And then make sure you transpile `node_modules/react-leaflet` during your build. If you are already using `@babel/preset-env` then you only need to make sure you're transpiling `react-leaflet` during the build. If you're using webpack you can do something like

```js
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      exclude: filename => {
        return /node_modules/.test(filename) && !/react-leaflet/.test(filename)
      },
      use: ['babel-loader']
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: for the '"plugins" : ["@babel...' I've already had that in the config. and can you explain transpiling react-leaflet again? because i'm new to reactjs and i didn't quite understand it, thank you @morganney

Comment: @aufa if you update your question to show your webpack config I can help more. You need to configure webpack to run babel-loader on react-leaflet to further transpile the `??` operator.